# bootstrap-select overlapped with other drop-down menus

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-select

Looking at bootstrap-select [examples](https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select/blob/master/test.html) no overlapping happened between different drop-down menus. However, in my examples all drop-down menus overlapping ( [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/brzu9hh4/)).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../docs-assets/ico/favicon.png">

    <title>TEST</title>


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/web.css">
    <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/non-responsive/non-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>


  <body>

    <!-- Fixed navbar -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">

        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/search/">TEST</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-collapsible">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">

            <li class="active"><a href="/search/">Home</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" method="get" action="/snearch/" role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="sid" placeholder="e.g. hello">
                    <button class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" type="submit"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="container">

      <form class="form-horizontal" action="/snps/" method="POST" role="form">
  <div style="display:none;"><input id="csrf_token" name="csrf_token" type="hidden" value="1413008961.84##d5f5a444ea1ef9d7ed3268e2e554bde2d2cc21e3"></div>
    <div class="input-group"> 

      <span class="input-group-addon">Test1:</span>
      <select class="selectpicker form-control" data-live-search="true" id="test_select" name="test_name">
            <option value="">--- Select One ---</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <BR/>   
    <div class="input-group"> 
      <span class="input-group-addon">Test2:</span>
      <select class="selectpicker form-control" data-live-search="true" id="test2_select" name="test2_name">
          <option value="">--- Select One ---</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
      </select>
    </div>      
    <BR/>   
    <div class="input-group">   
      <span class="input-group-addon">Test3:</span>
      <select class="selectpicker form-control" data-live-search="true" id="test3_select" name="test3_name">
            <option value="">--- Select One ---</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
      </select>
    </div>      
    <BR/> 
    <div class="input-group">   
      <span class="input-group-addon">test4:</span>
      <select class="selectpicker show-menu-arrow form-control" data-live-search="true" id="test4_select" multiple data-max-options="2" name="test4_names">
            <option value="">--- Select One ---</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>
            <option value="">Test</option>

      </select>
    </div>      
    <BR/>      
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">Start position:</span>
      <input class="form-control" id="start_pos" name="start_pos" placeholder="e.g. 200" type="number" value="">
      <span class="input-group-addon">End position:</span>
      <input class="form-control" id="end_pos" name="end_pos" placeholder="e.g. 1000" type="number" value="">
    </div>
    <BR/>    

    <div class="input-group">       
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Search</button>
      </span>
    </div>
</form>

    </div> <!-- /container -->

  <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.6.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();

  </script>  
  </body>
</html>
```

Maybe, I could use for everywhere *z-index*, but in bootstrap-select [examples](https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select/blob/master/test.html) they do not use it. How is it possible to avoid the use of *z-index*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

remove `z-index:2` from `.input-group .form-control` class it will work fine

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/brzu9hh4/1/)

Comment: Thank you, the overlapping is gone, but now on the top right corner the search symbol has changed. How is it possible to get it back?